# Error in django-app-metrics

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-apps

I am using [django-app-metrics](https://django-app-metrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing) for recording some metrics in my webapp. I using python3 and i installed app-metrics using following command - pip3 install django-app-metrics.

But when I am importing from app_metrics.utils import create_metric it is giving me this error :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/app_metrics/utils.py", line 92
except Exception, e
                ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: did you set the `app_metrics` to installed_apps list in your settings file ?

Comment: yes already done that.

Comment: Try installing `pip install django-app-metrics` without `pip3`

Comment: but that would be for python2 or lesser version i guess ?

Comment: And i don't have pip installed , i only have pip3 installed as I am using python3

Comment: `python3.6 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.6`

Comment: or can you suggest something better I just need to keep count of 3 variables which are initialised in my views.py and are incremented in some other file and will be accessed with new value in views.py file.

Comment: did the same but still same error.

Comment: Not sure, But looks like `django-app-metrics` support only python 2 not 3.

Comment: Any alternative for django-app-metrics for python3 ?